# Server tag is not well formed error is thrown when trying to pass a parameter binding a datasource's column

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to call a C# function from a `GridView` hyperlink passing a parameter but I get error that:

> Server tag is not well formed

on my aspx page. Here's what I am trying:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
        <a id="downloadLink" href="#" runat="server" OnServerClick ="download('<%# Eval("id") %>')"><%# Eval("title")%></a>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: pretty simple really. you have an "odd" tag: <%# Eval("title")%> unless your Evaluator is returning back the full correct tag to be rendered? The code is very smelly too. Plus you have 2 quotes which cancel each other out in a way on the OnServerClick attribute... you need to perhaps escape it.

Comment: No, that binding is working correctly, I get error when I am trying to pass the parameter <%# Eval("id") %>

Comment: it may work correctly but the code is very smelly. in any event, as I said...your tag evaluator here is not correct. you don't specify a tag. what is the value of Eval("title") ???

Comment: The value of Eval("title") is being got from a dataTable which is the dataSource of this gridView and "title" is one of the columns of the dataTable

Comment: what is THE VALUE of it?

Comment: you should probably think about changing the `OnServerClick` to `OnClick=` also you do not need the id of the download link in the `<a href=` section here is what I have just tried using email addresses on my own machine and inside of the ItemTemplate it works 
`<a href='<%#Eval("Email_Address") %>' ><%# Eval("Scheduler") %></a>` follow something like this should work..